# Including javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, dom

I want to include my own javascript code in the front page of a wordpress site. I have located it and have tried many ways online to add javascript code to it but either the console says it failed to load the resource or that the method I called is not defined when I try to use it in an "onload" attribute. I have looked for many articles online but they seem to be talking about how to use it in a specific post. I want this code for the front page only.

This is how I have included the javascript most recently in the header file:

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript"';
echo 'src="virtue-child/aboutUs.js"></script>'; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you have included your javascript? Or are you trying to do it through the WP control panel?

Comment: I tried in different ways to include the code: in the footer file, in the header file, in the actual file. At first I didn't even make it in an external file.

Comment: console says failed to load, that means it can't find the file. src is probably wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom script file in js folder of your theme and call in your theme function.php

Ex: your script file name ->customjquery.js

```
function custom_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'customjquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customjquery.js', array(), '0001', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tried your approach but there are two problems. The first is that this code only gets called if I turn the topbar on in the theme options. The second is that it looks for the file in the parent them and not the child theme even though that is the one that I set.

Comment: I have fixed the need for setting the topbar to on by changing wp_head to init in the code but in still gives me this error:

Comment: http://localhost/maths-society/wp-content/themes/virtue/assets/js/aboutUs.js?ver=0001 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Which doesn't make sense because I have the file saved in the folder called virtue-child and that is the current theme.

Comment: After making it direct to the child theme I am getting a 403 forbidden error

Comment: you can use get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); instead of get_template_directory_uri(). you can access childthme.

Comment: Yes, I used: get_stylesheet_directory() and that now gives me a 403 forbidden error even though it displays the right path.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, I put get_stylesheet_directory()  instead of get_stylesheet_directory_uri() as you suggested and that is why it didn't work